# Can we get more than one value from the proximity sensor per second?

Tags: android, android-ndk, proximitysensor

I need to detect the change in proximity sensor values per second and further use it in calculations. I tried the Android SDK method. But I found out that only one change or lesser, ( near->far or far->near ) can be detected per second. Is it a performance issue? I used `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`. I also tried it on two different phones ending up with the same result.

Will I get a higher frequency if the NDK is used?

If yes, how to get real time change per second values using the NDK? (NDK programming is too complex and beyond my scope).

I did try programming this in the NDK but all is got was constant values like `4.85016E-14`.

Help appreciated!